# How to run OpenCV Videocapture in a separate posix thread in C++ for cross-platform?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, pthreads, mingw32

In my code, I want to run a `Videocapture` in a separate `pthread` continuously, while the main thread will act as a `socket server` to communicate to any client (or vice versa).

When the `client` connects to the `server`, the `server` will immediately send the latest `Videocapture` frame to the client and close the connection and again wait for another connection.

I am currently using `OpenCV 2.3.0` in `mingw32` environment.

After looking some possible solutions on `StackOverflow`, I tried following them, but, however may I place the OpenCV `variables` either `locally` or `globally` or `swapping the threads` i.e. keeping `Videocapture` thread in `main thread` or `in the 2nd thread`, the program just hangs silently at the `mutex locked area` of the `VideoCapture` thread when the client gets connected.

I suppose this is happening when the `server` thread starts locking the `mutex` after connecting to a client.

Any **reasoning** or **possible solution** will be highly appreciated. Also, I am using **prebuilt** OpenCV version 2.3.0 and I need the code to be cross platform. In any case, if it points to a bug, I can obviously switch to some other version.

---

**Server code**

**mynet.h**

```
#ifndef __MYNET__
#define __MYNET__
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501  /* Windows XP. */
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#else
/* Assume that any non-Windows platform uses POSIX-style sockets instead. */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>  /* Needed for getaddrinfo() and freeaddrinfo() */
#include <unistd.h> /* Needed for close() */
#endif

int sockInit(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsa_data);
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}

int sockQuit(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return WSACleanup();
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}

/* Note: For POSIX, typedef SOCKET as an int. */
#ifndef _WIN32
typedef int SOCKET;
#else
typedef unsigned int SOCKET;
#endif

int sockClose(SOCKET sock)
{
    int status = 0;
#ifdef _WIN32
    status = shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    if (status == 0) { status = closesocket(sock); }
#else
    status = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) { status = close(sock); }
#endif
    return status;
}


#if(defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32))
#include <windows.h>
#define mysleep(x) Sleep((x))
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define mysleep(x) usleep((x)*1000)
#endif

#endif
```

**netserver.cpp**

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#include "../mynet.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace cv;
Mat frame(120, 160, CV_8UC3);;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_t thread;

void *myfunc(void *threadid)
{
    int n;
    int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    unsigned char sendBuff[160*120*3];
    Mat hereframe;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("socket retrieve success\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    if(listen(listenfd, 10) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to listen\n");
    }
    else
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL);  // accept awaiting request
        if(connfd<=0)  printf("Something went wrong with write()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        else
        {
            while(1)
            {
                printf("Got client...\n");
                pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
                printf("Copying data...\n");
                frame.copyTo(hereframe);
                pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
                printf("Hereframe size: %dX%d\n", hereframe.rows, hereframe.cols);
                memcpy(sendBuff, hereframe.data, 120*160*3);
                printf("Sending data...\n");
                n = send(connfd, (char*)sendBuff, 120*160*3,0);
                if(n<0)  printf("Something went wrong with write()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
                printf("Closing client after writing %d bytes...\n", n);
                printf("Closed...\n");
                mysleep(40);
                printf("Restartng data...\n");
            }
            sockClose(connfd);
        }
    }
    sockQuit();

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    //cvNamedWindow("Sisplay", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    sockInit();
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    VideoCapture cap;
    Mat hereframe1;
    cap.open(0);
    cap.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160 );
    cap.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120 );

    if( !cap.isOpened()) printf("Fukced up\n");
    int rc;
    long t;
    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myfunc, (void *)t);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> hereframe1;
        //     printf("Video size: %dX%d\n", hereframe1.rows, hereframe1.cols);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        hereframe1.copyTo(frame); /* hangs here*/
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        // cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        Scalar tempVal = mean(hereframe1);
        //  printf("Mean = %f\n", tempVal.val[0]);
        mysleep(30);
        //if(waitKey(30)=='q') break;
        // std::swap(prevgray, gray);
    }
    char *b;
    pthread_join(thread,(void**)&b);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Client code**

**receiver.cpp**

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
#include "../mynet.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
    unsigned char recvBuff[120*160*3];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sockInit();
    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected to server...\n");
    Mat frame(120, 160, CV_8UC3);
    int csz = 0;
    cvNamedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    printf("OK here 0\n");
    for(;;)
    {
        csz = 0;
        while((n = recv(sockfd, (char*)recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0)) > 0)
        {
            printf("OK here 2\n");

            printf("Read %d bytes...\n", n);
            csz += n;
            if(csz<=120*160*3)
            {
                memcpy(frame.data+(csz-n), recvBuff, n);
            }
            if(csz>= 120*160*3) break;
        }
        printf("OK here 3\n");

        printf("Got data of size %d bytes...\n", csz);
        imshow("Display", frame);
        if(csz < 120*160*3)
        {
            printf("\n Read Error \n");
        }
        if(waitKey(30)=='q') break;
        // std::swap(prevgray, gray);
    }
    sockClose(sockfd);

    sockQuit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is VideoCapture  `cap.open(-1);`  I'm learning OpenCV too, but the `-1` thing baffles me.. I know what `0, 1, 2...` is, but what does the `-1` signify?  Also, why is frame set to `Mat frame(120, 160, CV_8UC3);`?  Why not simply `Mat frame;` ?

Comment: @zipzit: Nevermind, it should be 0. I have corrected. I have set the size of `frame` earlier because, after lot of swapping and altering the variables during my debugging, sometime it was happening that before the Videocapture starts, the client was connecting. In that case, the server thread cannot copy the raw data of `frame` with size `120x160x3` bytes in the mutex locked region without prior sizing.

Comment: I'm wondering about the global variable `frame`... I thought the way you've called it out is good for enums and constants.. but not so much for an active variable.  Does this need the global scope operator `(::)` ?

Comment: the global `frame` is used as the carrier of data between the two threads protected by the `mutex`. Okay, I somehow managed to solve it. Please see below.

Comment: Just a suggestion; if you need the code to be cross platform, you can consider using [c++11 thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: @dhanushka: Surely, but I am not using C++11.

Answer (score 2):

What I think is that the OpenCV 2.3.0 functions are not thread-safe. e.g. functions like Mat::clone(), Mat::copyTo, etc. (need to clarify).

So, instead of using those `OpenCV functions` in `mutex locked regions` and `OpenCV variables` as a whole shared in multiple threads, I am just using basic C++ functions and raw buffers.

Using `OpenCV functions` in `mutex locked regions` and `OpenCV variables` as a whole shared in multiple threads does not seem to be friendly at all.

So, I have made a change in the server thread as

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
//printf("Copying data...\n");
memcpy(sendBuff, frame.data, 120*160*3);
//frame.copyTo(hereframe);  buggy here removed 
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
```

And now Its working as expected. Uffh! Now, I need to clean up all the mess in my code.

In fact, I will also replace the OpenCV `frame` variable with a simple `unsigned char` buffer for the sharing.

Comment: I've not tried OpenCV in a threaded application yet.  Thanks for sharing the discovery.  (Note: was there a reference for this "not thread safe" behavior, or was this a deduction based on a lot of testing failures?)

Comment: @zipzit: I cannot say it exactly. It is just a doubt. Firstly, I am not an expert in OpenCV. Furthermore, I am just using a particular (old) version of it.